# How can I write a pivot that takes this form of data to the result desired?

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table, table-functions

I have a table that looks like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (id, name, category)
AS VALUES
  ( 1, 'name1.1', 'cat1.1.1'),
  ( 1, 'name1.2', 'cat1.1.1'),
  ( 1, 'name1.3', 'cat1.2.1'),
  ( 2, 'name2.1', 'cat2.1.1'),
  ( 2, 'name2.2', 'cat2.1.1'),
  ( 3, 'name3.1', 'cat3.1.1')
;
```

I'm trying to get a result that looks like this,

| Id | name1 | name2 | name3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1.1 | name1.2 | name1.3 |
| 2 | name2.1 | name2.2 |  |
| 3 | name3.1 |  |  |

Comment: Search for pivot or crosstab.

Comment: I tried crosstab. Didn't get what I want. Don't see pivot as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would aggregate all names into an array, then extract the array elements as columns:

```
select id, 
       names[1] as name1,
       names[2] as name2,
       names[3] as name3
from (
   select id, 
          array_agg(name order by name) as names
   from foo
   group by id
) t
```

If the names could contain things like `name10.11` then the order of the columns won't be numerical because the string `'10'` is lower than the string `'2'`. If you want the order to reflect the numbers, the sorting gets a bit more complicated:

```
array_agg(name order by string_to_array(replace(name, 'name', ''), '.')::int[]) as names
```

This removes the `name` prefix and converts the numbers to an integer array which then sorts properly. Another option is to remove everything that's not a digit or dot:

```
array_agg(name order by string_to_array(regexp_replace(name, '[^0-9.]', '', 'g'), '.')::int[]) as names
```

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to add [the `tablefunc` module which provides this ability.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html)

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

Now you need a query like this,

```sql
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    -- here we normalize this into `id | cat | value`
    -- where the category is [1-3]
    $$SELECT id, RIGHT(name,1)::int AS cat, name AS value FROM foo ORDER BY 1,2;$$,
    -- For just the cat 1,2,3
    $$VALUES (1),(2),(3);$$
) AS ct(id text, name1 text, name2 text, name3 text);
```

Which will return this,

```
 id |  name1  |  name2  |  name3  
----+---------+---------+---------
 1  | name1.1 | name1.2 | name1.3
 2  | name2.1 | name2.2 | 
 3  | name3.1 |         | 
(3 rows)
```

Notice the big gotcha here, your catagory is actually a function of your data `RIGHT(name,1)::int`. That was probably your hold up. Conversely, the actual data you provided in `category` is seemingly safe to ignore entirely unless I'm missing something.

Also note that I hardcoded the catagory names in two places,

```
$$VALUES (1),(2),(3);$$
```

And,

```
ct(id text, name1 text, name2 text, name3 text);
```

This is required, as PostgreSQL doesn't allow you to return a query where the result set is not known when you run the command. This will support only `[name1 - name3]`If you want it truly dynamic the scope of the program grows a lot and it's off topic on this question.

Comment: I think I should have been clearer in my question. I cannot extract the id from the name. It's always followed by random numbers. 
Eg: John_054745460131 will not be the same as Jane_054745460131. 

You were right to ignore the 3rd category column. So, I only have the 2 columns(id and name) to rely on.

Comment: @JohnDoe Nothing changes =) Just update the values. I was just showing you the ["Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Try this answer with this data, `CREATE TABLE foo (id, name, category)
AS VALUES
  ( 'john_1', 'name1.1', 'cat1.1.1'),
  ( 'john_1', 'name1.2', 'cat1.1.1'),
  ( 'jane_1', 'name1.3', 'cat1.2.1'),
  ( 'john_2', 'name2.1', 'cat2.1.1'),
  ( 'jane_2', 'name2.2', 'cat2.1.1'),
  ( 'john_3', 'name3.1', 'cat3.1.1')
;` I assume that's still what you want.

Comment: This is the data I'm working with. 
CREATE TABLE foo (id, name, category) AS VALUES   ( '1', 'john1.1', 'cat1.1.1'),  ( '1', 'john1.2', 'cat1.1.1'),   ( '1', 'john1.3', 'cat1.2.1'),   ( '2', 'jane2.1', 'cat2.1.1'),   ( '2', 'jane2.2', 'cat2.1.1'),   ( '3', 'jake3.1', 'cat3.1.1')

Comment: @JohnDoe At this point, I simply do not understand what you want. I would very cautiously edit this question though and update it with the right information but change nothing of the form! Follow the current form of question. Also update and show your desired output.